# How to match only strings that do not contain special character (using regular expressions)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regexp that only matches strings if they don't contain a `@ or empty or http: or https:` 
e.g. it matches `stackoverflow, 42abc47 or a-bc-31_4` but doesn't match:

```
swp@aa, '', https:stackoverflow or http:test.
```

I tried to come up with this `/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i`
Will this work??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
/^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test('www.google.com')
```